# How to find how many columns of two numpy arrays match with each other?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `(10,10000)` numpy array matrices with `0's` and `1's` only. I want to count how many columns match. As an example:

```
ms
Out[164]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])

y_en
Out[165]: 
array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

last column of both `ms` and `y_en` match so I should get `1` (Only one column match found). I tried `len(ms[ms==y_en])` but obviously that is not comparing column wise. What's the proper way to find how many columns match?

Comment: The above solution works faster, but you could also transpose the matrices and check (then you only have 10 rows to check), and check if each row of your matrices match. Not as elegant, mortysporty's solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
import numpy as np
ms = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
               [0., 1., 1., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
y_en = np.array([[0., 1., 0., 1.],
                 [1., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 1., 0.]])

np.count_nonzero(np.sum(abs(ms-y_en), axis=0) == 0)
```

So basically you subtract the two arrays and count the number of columns where the sum of the absoulute value of the difference is zero.

Comment: Haha. Lots of comments. You deleted them all before I had time to respond :)

Comment: Haha yes a bit confusing. I'm just going to delete all of them. +1